# ac/dc adapter input amperage rating

Tags: power-supply, transformer

if you have a control circuit of 120V on the secondary side of a transformer which you have fused at 1.5 A since you are using a 150VA dry type and you connect a wall outlet plug in that 120V circuit and the device's ac/dc power adapter has an input rating of up to 1.5A on from 100-240V then won't potentially blow your secondary fuse on the transformer since it is pulling 1.5As?

Comment: @DKNguyen  i mean an actual one. i'm worried that as soon as i plug this device in it might potentially pull slightly more then 1.5As and cause the secondary fuse to blow.

Comment: Your post is a bit incoherent. Draw a schematic. This website has a schematic editor. Hit edit.

Comment: Please edit your post so that it has proper sentence structure.

Answer (score 1):

Your post is incoherent since it is super not obvious what connections there are or if you are even talking about two, three or four components. You refer to control circuits and devices which may or may not be the same thing; I can't tell. Things with plugs seem to be plugging into outlets that may or may not be located on the wall or transformer; It is unclear.

Picking the only part that made sense:

> device's ac/dc power adapter has an input rating of up to 1.5A on from 100-240V then won't potentially blow your secondary fuse on the transformer since it is pulling 1.5As?

I'm assuming this is the answer to your question.

The input rating on a **power supply** is what it pulls when providing the maximum output rating. In the same way the maximum output of a power supply doesn't mean it must to supply that, the input rating doesn't mean it must to pull that.